# Implementation: Why is `reduce` not variadic

Tags: clojure

E. g. why can `reduce` not be used with multiple input sequences as its arguments like `map`, `mapv`?

What are the implementors/Rich Hickeys reasons behind that decision?

Would it affect performance, if so how? Is it simply language design that wants to lead us in the "right" direction, if so why?

EDIT: As found out in the discussion (with the help of @Alex), here are the overloads of a variadic `reduce`

`([f coll])`

`([f val & colls])` (because an initial accumulator would be required in the variadic scenario).

So even if it was made variadic today, nothing about its current behavior would change.

Comment: Suppose there were such a `reduce` variant. What arguments would you expect the function that you pass it to take?

Comment: The accumulator and `n` more arguments representing for-one element of the input sequences, like `map` does..

Comment: The first element of the collection is taken as the initial value of the accumulator for `reduce` if none is provided, which would not work for the variadic case. Which is not to say that you couldn't easily write your own version that requires an initial value, it just wouldn't have exactly the same semantics.

Comment: Great point! That is why it would be possible to implement the variadic version of it as an overload to `reduce` where an initial value needs to be provided.

Comment: @Alex: Please see a possible combination of overloads in my comment to mikeras answer. It *would* have the same semantics.

Comment: Funny that someone downvoted this today given that now Clojure 1.7 implements variadic reducing functions with transducers and variadic reduction via `sequence`.

Answer (score 2):

It already is variadic (in the sense of supporting more than one arity):

```
=> (doc reduce)
-------------------------
clojure.core/reduce
([f coll] [f val coll])
  f should be a function of 2 arguments. If val is not supplied,
  returns the result of applying f to the first 2 items in coll, then
  applying f to that result and the 3rd item, etc. If coll contains no
  items, f must accept no arguments as well, and reduce returns the
  result of calling f with no arguments.  If coll has only 1 item, it
  is returned and f is not called.  If val is supplied, returns the
  result of applying f to val and the first item in coll, then
  applying f to that result and the 2nd item, etc. If coll contains no
  items, returns val and f is not called.
```

If you made it variadic even further (e.g. allowing an arbitrary number of collections) then the 3 argument case would be **ambiguous** - did you mean to pass an initial value, or two different collections?

IMHO making functions variadic in more than one different aspect is something of an anti-pattern. Just because you can change the meaning of functions with arity overloads doesn't mean it is a good idea: you are often better off explicitly achieving the same effect by composing higher order functions.

Comment: Afaic *variadic* means an indefinite amount of arguments, not overloads of different arities. At least that is what I mean. I know that `reduce` is not implemented in a way to support it. That is why I asked about design decisions.

Comment: @lgrapenthin, you can use `map` to achieve the same effect `(reduce f acc (map vector coll1 coll2 coll3))`. Note that `filter` doesn't support multiple collections either.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible with `map`. But `map` is lazy and thus unnecessary per-step overhead would be generated, also for reducers  vectors are needed as input. I don't think how variadic input to `filter` would make any sense at all.

Comment: Also, it is not correct that it would be ambiguous, because you could not invoke reduce variadically without specifying an initial accumulator. The variadic overload would be (`[f val coll & colls]`) where `colls` are optional. The two argument (`[f coll]`) overload could stay to be the only one without an initial value (were the initial value is the first element of coll or f).